# Cannot connect to google account tablet

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google

I have a tablet and an older smartphone that I wish to use as a mini-tablet.  while the tablet does have Play functioning I cannot log in to google account for other purposes. It just says cannot connect to server.  WiFi is fine. Can surf web etc. no problem.

On the smart phone I cannot even log in to my Play account with the app. Same error but nothing seems wrong, just won't let me log in to install apps. Cannot connect to google account either.  This is a Chinese smart phone not being used for data/phone, just as a tablet.

Comment: What is the model?  What version of Android?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with google account signin and signup all over the world today

check this for more info : http://mashable.com/2016/04/19/google-oauth-down/#I8jZi7QGiuqN

You can check now it's live.